# Pass struct vs individual struct elements

Tags: c, function, struct

In C, if a struct has multiple elements and you want to use only some of those elements in a function, is it better to pass a pointer to the struct or should I pass the elements themselves? Or does it not make a difference?

If I have, for example:

```
struct Test {
    int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8;
};
```

and a function that uses a1, a2, a3, a4, should I use

```
void f(struct Test*);
```

or

```
void f(int, int, int, int);
```

Comment: I would pass just what I need, that is, individual struct elements.

Comment: But then I am passing multiple things instead of just a pointer. Is one better than the other?

Comment: This is likely to get closed shortly because it's subjective.  But for my twopence I'd say it depends on on the function.  If your function can only be used with this structure (despite only using a subset of fields) then pass the structure.  If it has a chance of being reused in other places by passing the individual fields then it makes sense to do that.

Comment: question is probably better worded as: when should i use this and that over this and the other thing?

Comment: Nothing is "better" than the other in the general case. This is _far_ too vague.

Comment: I would always pass the pointer to the struct.  Then later maintenance, debugging, etc will only have to modify the contents of the function and not all the places where the function is called, etc.  This also works when the definition of the struct is modified.

Comment: It's more difficult to see what the function actually needs if the whole struct is passed: one has to assume that the whole struct is needed unless he/she dig deep into the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a little difference. Passing individual struct elements will allocate memory for each value, since you're passing by value, not by reference. Passing a struct pointer only needs memory to allocate an address.

Which looks better? That's subjective, there's no *right* answer.

Comment: it's more than just stack memory allocation.  there's also the time to copy elements onto the stack.  also, sometimes it depends on the use case where it's not subjective.

Comment: @thang That's right, thanks for improving :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the function is designed to deal with the structure then of course it is better to declare it like:

```
void f(struct Test*);
```

or

```
void f(struct Test);
```

depending on whether the original argument should be changed in the function.

On the other hand if the function is designed to deal with some four integer values then it is better to declare it like this:

```
void f(int *, int *, int *, int *);
```

or

```
void f(int, int, int, int);
```

again depending on how the arguments should be processed in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example the difference is indeed negligible. In a way it's like passing one integer value against four integer values. In your case I'd rather use

`void f(const struct Test*);`

It will provide better maintainability when you decide to make changes to you function. Plus it guards you against accidental changes to the struct.